# Why does JavaScript round up this number when I log it to the console?

Tags: javascript

Why does:

```js
console.log( 9999999999999999 ); //log 10000000000000000
```

This [article](https://javascript.info/number) mentions it but I don't actually understand why

Comment: IEEE floating point represents every number as (53-bit value) x 2^(11-bit value). 9999999999999999 is a 54-bit value, so it cannot be represented exactly. The closest matches are 0x11ce7937e07fff x 2^1 0x11ce7937e08000 x 2^1, which are 9999999999999999 and 10000000000000000, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because javascript handle numbers like this. You should take it into account to not fail.
You can read about this here.
http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch11.html

> For 54 bits, the least significant digit is always 0, for 55 bits the two least significant digits are always 0, and so on. That means that for 54 bits, we can only represent every second number, for 55 bits only every fourth number, and so on. For example:

> Math.pow(2, 53) - 1  // OK
> 9007199254740991 
> Math.pow(2, 53)  // OK
> 9007199254740992 
> Math.pow(2, 53) + 1  // can't be represented
> 9007199254740992 
> Math.pow(2, 53) + 2  // OK
> 9007199254740994

> Best practice

> If you work with integers of up to 53 bits magnitude, you are fine. Unfortunately, you’ll often encounter 64-bit unsigned integers in programming (Twitter IDs, databases, etc.). These must be stored in strings in JavaScript. If you want to perform arithmetic with such integers, you need special libraries. There are plans to bring larger integers to JavaScript, but that will take a while.